# Expected Value of $X \sin(X)$ with $X$ normally distributed

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value

I want to solve the following expected value problem. Let's say $X$ is normally distributed so that $X \sim N(m,s^2)$. I want to find the expected value,

$$E[X\sin(X)]$$

that is equal to

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s^2}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(\frac{_{-(x-m)^2}}{^{2s^2}})\,  x\,\sin(x)\, dx$$

Does anyone have an idea how to simplify this?

EDIT: thanks guys for helping me out!

Comment: For m=0, it evaluates to `s2*exp(-s2/2)`. It's messier if m is not zero, with the result `(1/2)*exp(-I*m-(1/2)*s2)*s2-((1/2)*I)*exp(I*m-(1/2)*s2)*m+((‌​1/2)*I)*exp(-I*m-(1/‌​2)*s2)*m+(1/2)*exp(I‌​*m-(1/2)*s2)*s2` , in which the imaginary, `I`, terms will cancel out when evaluated.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone That seems like it should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @ Kodiologist I didn't want someone bitching at me for not having a nicely finished and formatted answer.

Comment: Looper, please carefully examine all the edits made to your original question, in the grammar, spelling, capitalization, [formatting of mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and so on. In particular note the necessity for distinction between the symbols for $X$, the random variable and $x$, the dummy variable in the integral.

Comment: The s2 in my comment above corresponds to what has now been edited in the question statement to be $s^2$.

Comment: @mark please check your comment is okay now. If you want to paste an answer, right click on the expressions in your comment, choose *Show Math As* --> *TeX Commands* and you should be able to copy the MathJax markup and paste the results between \$\$ signs to get a reasonably formatted answer.

Comment: @Glen_b I think your edit to my comment messed it up.  i don't have time to deal with it now.

Comment: @mark My apologies. I was pretty careful actually, but I have replaced it by pasting a copy of the text you originally had (except it was necessary to reinsert the backticks \` \`; I forgot they wouldn't carry over)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like many exercises involving trigonometric functions, the trick is to use complex numbers, *i.e.*, $\int(\sin(x))\mathrm{d}x = \int Im(e^{ix})\mathrm{d}x = Im(\int e^{ix} \mathrm{d}x)$ here.

Knowing, the sum becomes
\begin{align}
 I \triangleq \mathbb{E}[X\sin(X)] = Im \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} x e^{ix} e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} (x-\mu)^2} \mathrm{d}x \right) .
\end{align}

To compute this sum, we have to factorise the two exponential terms.
A rule of thumb for such calculation is that a gaussian stays gaussian when multiplied by an exponential term of the form $e^{ax}$.
I let you do the math, but one can write
\begin{equation}  
-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} (x-\mu)^2 + ix = -\frac{1}{2 \sigma^2}\big( x- (\mu+i\sigma^2) \big)^2 + i\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2} .
\end{equation}

Then, by recognising the expectation of a new gaussian distribution
\begin{align}
I =& Im \left( e^{-\frac{\sigma^2}{2} + i\mu} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} x e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x - \mu - i\sigma^2)^2} \mathrm{d}x \right) \\
=& Im \left( e^{-\frac{\sigma^2}{2} + i\mu} \times (\mu + i \sigma^2) \right) \\
=&e^{-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}} \times \left( \sigma^2 \cos(\mu) + \mu \sin(\mu) \right),
\end{align}

which corresponds to wolfies's answer.

Comment: did you miss the x in the last integral?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this error, it has been corrected accordingly.

Comment: sorry for reopening, but x is still missing, right?

Comment: Sorry, yes $x$ was still missing, because it is an expectation. I only corrected the $\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: Note that this can also be solved quickly using the same trick with the moment-generating function

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried a computer algebra system? Here $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ with pdf $f(x)$:

[image]
Here is the output from *mathStatica / Mathematica*:

[image]

Comment: I dont have Mathematica, is this also possible with Matlabs Symbolic Toolbox?